# capitalize vowels in a string java

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a way to make an inputted string's vowels become capitalized after counting the vowels within it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //        Vowels test = new Vowels();   //comment out this line
    System.out.println("enter a string"); //Says enter String
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  //Com reads the input
    String str = kb.nextLine();     // this is the String variable to the input
  //  char vowel = str.charAt(p);
    int count = 0;          //this counts thee vowels
    for(int p = 0; p<str.length(); p++)         // p is the looping for the char vowel
        {
            char vowel = str.charAt(p);
                                                    //.Character.toUppercase(); //Character.toUpperCase doesn't work so much here... 
                                        //  char vOwEl = Character.toUpperCase(vowel); //Adding a new char doesnt work either
            switch (vowel)
            {/* I forget the single quotes here...*/
            case 'a':
               // a-=32;
                /*Character.toUpperCase('a');
                count++;
                break;//didn't work...*/
            case 'e':
               // e-=32;
                /*Character.toUpperCase('e');
                count++;
                break; */
            case 'i':
                //i-=32;
               /* Character.toUpperCase('i');
                count++;
                break;*/
            case 'o':
               // o-=32;
               /* Character.toUpperCase('o');
                count++;
                break;*/
            case 'u':
                //u-=32;
                //Character.toUpperCase('u');
                count++;
                                                             //System.out.println("There are "+count+"vowels in the string: "+str);
                break;
            default:
                                                             //System.out.println("There is no vowels.");
                                                             // no code since it will print out "there is no vowels" a number of times
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are "+count+" vowels in the string: "+str);


    //        test.countVowels(str);    //comment out this line
}
}
```

Comment: Your question essentially is: `"here are some broad requirements and here is some code"` and that's about it. These sort of questions are **very** hard to answer well and usually get closed. Please tell us more about this code, what it does, what it is not doing that it is supposed to do, and please try to ask a much more specific and answerable question and you'll likely get a decent and specific answer. A rule of thumb is that the better the quality of the question, the better the quality and quicker the answer.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code, it counts vowels.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to replace the characters at the positions you want with the characters you want

Comment: Well, to follow up on your comment Hovercraft, the matter is that I have already figured out the way to count the vowels of an inputted string. it it simply now modifying the code to get a string like "hello friend" to return as "hEllO frIEnd". That's what I needed help on.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable. I would use a `StringBuilder`. And I would prefer an `if` to that complicated `switch` statement. Also, I'd use formatted output at the end. Something like,

```
System.out.println("enter a string");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = kb.nextLine();
int count = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    char t = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
    if (t == 'A' || t == 'E' || t == 'I' || t == 'O' || t == 'U') {
        sb.append(t);
        count++;
    } else {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
}
System.out.printf("There are %d vowels in the string: %s%n", count,
        sb.toString());
```

Comment: This is probably a personal choice, but given the limited range of possible values, a `switch` statement is probably slightly easier to read then a `if` statement, but that's just me ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Use a `StringBuilder` to store and modify the characters at the positions you want to.
- Use the `Character` class to convert a character to upper/lower case

For example

```
System.out.println("enter a string"); //Says enter String
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  //Com reads the input
String str = kb.nextLine();     // this is the String variable to the input
int count = 0;          //this counts thee vowels
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.toLowerCase());
for (int p = 0; p < str.length(); p++) // p is the looping for the char vowel
{
    char vowel = str.charAt(p);
    switch (vowel) {/* I forget the single quotes here...*/

        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            result.setCharAt(p, Character.toUpperCase(vowel));
            count++;
            break;
    }
}

str = result.toString();
System.out.println("There are " + count + " vowels in the string: " + str);
```